# Como passar variável no require

Tags: javascript, react, import

Eu estou tentando passar uma variável populada pelo banco de dados, contendo minha rota para o require, mas está dando o seguinte erro:

```
"Cannot find module 'views/Cadastros/Usuario'"
```

E estas as formas que tentei realizar a importação e que infelizmente não deram certo

```
var component = require("" + listRouters[i].import).default 

var component = await (await import(listRouters[i].import).default;

var component = import(listRouters[i].import)
```

Comment: Inclua mais detalhes do código para que o problema possa ser avaliado.

Comment: Qual é o caminho do modulo que queres adicionar?

Comment: o caminho é esse 'views/Cadastros/Usuario'

Comment: dentro da listRouters[i].import tenho 'views/Cadastros/Usuario', o import normal funciona bem.